# How to convert dictionaries of dataframes(stored as values) to one CSV?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I need some advice on how to convert a dictionary of dataframes to one CSV?

below is my structure

```
dic_dataframe { "Key value 1":DF1,"Key value 2":DF2}
```

in above DF1 is like

```
index A B C
0     a b c
1     x y z
2     1 2 3
```

and DF2 has same number of columns and columns names are same as well just different rows

```
index A B C
0     w x y
1     3 4 5
```

i am  expecting a csv file which looks like as follows

```
index Key_Values  A B C
0     Key value 1 a b c
1     Key value 1 x y z
2     Key value 1 1 2 3
3     Key Value 2 w x y
4     Key Value 2 3 4 5
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated as i have tried many thing but cant get this to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `dictionary of`, remove second level of `MultiIndex` by first [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), then for new column name add [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and last use `reset_index` for convert index to column:

```
dic_dataframe = { "Key value 1":DF1,"Key value 2":DF2}

df = (pd.concat(dic_dataframe)
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .rename_axis('Key_Values')
        .reset_index())
print (df)
    Key_Values  A  B  C
0  Key value 1  a  b  c
1  Key value 1  x  y  z
2  Key value 1  1  2  3
3  Key value 2  w  x  y
4  Key value 2  3  4  5
```

Last write to csv by [`DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
df.to_csv(file, index=False)
```